# Simple Div/CSS layout not working as expected

Tags: css

I am trying to create simple horizontal stack over words while playing around with CSS and I have noticed that it is impossible to stack two divs horizontally while centering one's content when other div is empty.

Here is the example in question. I tried it in chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/mncmN/

```
<div style="margin: 0px; height:50px; width:100%; border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.1); background: url(menu-back.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; font-family: helvetica; color: rgba(50,50,50,0.8);">
    <div style="text-align:center; display: inline-block;  "> <a>Summary</a>

    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;  display: inline-block; height: 100%; border-right: solid gray 1px;"></div>
</div>
```

Why is that so?

To summarize, I need three things together.

1) Inline div blocks stacks horizontally

2) Text within them aligned in center(relative to parent container).

3) empty div boxes which will act as border.

Comment: Sorry to say but Your question is not clear? Also can u modify ur example by adding classes (with suitable names) instead of inline style? meanwhile if u r looking for some horizontal alignment of divs why float property is not used?

Comment: But when I look at your fiddle, they are stacked horizontally... Could you post some simple image of the desired result? Just rectangles representing divs.

Comment: I edited the question with 3 exact points which I am looking for.

Comment: updated my answer - Took at look at the 3 things you needed help with. I think that is what you were looking for. Each div can have it's border and is fluid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lloanalas/mncmN/6/) - Is that what you are looking for exactly?

```
<div class="container"  >

    <div class="left">1</div>

    <div class="center">2</div>

    <div class="right">3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: yup exactly what I was looking for. That means, it is not possible to do it with just div? I have to introduce an anchor element and split horizontal & vertical alignment across parent, child node. Correct?

Comment: well the 'a' tag is there because you had it there - I wanted to turn it into a 'p' tag - let me update that.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Here is the **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/mncmN/3/)**

**The Code:**

```
    <div style="margin: 0px; height:50px; width:100%; border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.1); background: url(menu-back.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; font-family: helvetica; color: rgba(50,50,50,0.8); display:table;">
    <div style="text-align:center; display: table-cell; background:#cccccc; vertical-align:middle; "> <a>Summary</a></div>
    <div style="text-align:center;  display: table-cell; background:gray; vertical-align:middle; height: 100%; border-right: solid gray 1px;">sdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but then the text-align: center is lost.

Comment: Its not, both are at the center.

Comment: yup, I think I need to go buy a CSS book :) Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Parth You can always try a free trial at  TeamTreeHouse.com - It's pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your empty div: `&nbsp;`. It's a white space. The div will still look empty, but now you can set the width and the height.

Also, try to separate the CSS from the html, like in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WzymM/

Answer (score 0):

Please view the sample [http://jsfiddle.net/mncmN/5/][1] . Hope this was your question? `

```
<div style="margin: 0px; border: solid red 1px; width:100%; border-bottom: solid 1px black;">
     <div style=" border: solid gray 1px; text-align:center; display: inline-block; "> <a>Summary</a>
    </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align:center; border: solid gray 1px;">ff </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align:center; border: solid gray 1px;"> </div>
    </div>`


      [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/mncmN/5/
```